# PHP, Conditional "If..Then..Else" to Remove Based on Certain Delimiter

Tags: php

I have a variable **$example** which can take such values:

```
 - $example = "Black +0 USD"

 - $example = "Red +42 USD"

 - $example = "White +0.5 USD"
```

I need an IF type of function that will take this value and if there is a **"+0 USD"** then to delete it and return just the name to something like this

```
 - $example = "Black"

 -  $example = "Red +42 USD"

 -  $example = "White +0.5 USD"
```

If there is a value other than **+0 USD** to return the original string

Anybody has any suggestions?
Thank you

Comment: `strpos`+ `substr`. Now it's your turn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$example = "Black +0 USD";

 if(strpos($example, '+0 USD')){

    str_replace('+0 USD', '', $example); // or do something... 
  }else{
    //do something..
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use string replace

```
str_replace("+0 USD", "", $example);
```

So your function would be:

```
function clean($example) {
    return  str_replace("+0 USD", "", $example);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I tried it but i received this error:  **"cannot redeclare clean() previously declared"** Is there something i am doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like you have a `clean` function.  Pick a different name for this function.

Comment: there is no other function with clean. this goes in a loop so maybe that's why it appears the error, but how can it be fixed?

Comment: Declare your function outside of the loop, not in the loop.

Comment: it has to be in the loop, other wise there is no use for it.

Comment: I meant you declare/define your function outside the loop, and call it inside the loop.